# Add Images in Magento Theme template file

Tags: magento2, image, phtml, image-preview

I want to add image like `footer.png` in

**app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml**

Here I am adding image using

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Company_Module::images/image-icon.png'); ?>' alt="image-icon" width="30" height="25"
```

Image In `Magento_Theme/web/images` folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$this->getViewFileUrl('Company_Module::images/image-icon.png');
```

Your image should put under `web` folder in your custom module: `app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/images/image-icon.png`

Comment: @MoinMalek you're welcome!

Comment: how can i get the image in the default.html file?

Comment: @SUBBULAKSHMIG what do you mean? your question is not clear to me.