# How to get media directory path in a phtml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, media, directory, paths

Used the below method in order to get the **media** directory path, but it returns an error.

```
$om = \Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$directoryList = $om->get(\Magento\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::class);

$pubMediaDir = $directoryList->getPath(\Magento\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You can explain more details? Additionally, we can take a look: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155238/33057

Comment: @Rita Jose, does the accepted answer fit in a .phtml file which doesn't have any class?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Instead of using direct `object manager`, use It like

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
}
```

Now you can media path by,

```
$mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use an **Object Manager**, then you can use this (not recommended)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
echo $mediaPath;
exit;
```

Comment: it returns an error like this " Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to namespace\Module\Controller\Index\Upload::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Filesystem, none given,"

Comment: yes, try to di:compile and try again :)

Comment: di:compile done, but it again returns a errror :(    "Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento214/app/code/namespace/Customtab/Controller/Index/Upload.php on line 18"

Comment: see my edit, If you want to use direct object manager  @RitaJose

Comment: @KeyurShah, Would you please suggest how to get Custom module's image folder directory path? I want to get directory path of my module's image folder.

Comment: how to save the image to the media folder

Comment: small change required, I think you declare variable $_filesystem but used $filesystem in constructor, that should be $_filesystem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

First you will need to inject DirectoryList class into your Magento 2 constructor:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list, array $data = []) {
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
     $this->directory_list = $directory_list;  
 }
```

After that you will have access to DirectoryList methods for retrieving various paths. For example, to get media folder you can use:

```
$this->directory_list->getPath('media');
```

Other possible uses are:

```
/* Get app folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('app');

/* Get configuration folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('etc');

/* Get libraries or third-party components folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('lib_internal');

/* Get libraries/components that need to be accessible publicly through web-server folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('lib_web');

/* Get public folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('pub');

/* Get static folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('static');

/* Get var folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('var');

/* Get temporary files folder */
$this->directory_list->getPath('tmp');

/* Get file system caching directory (if file system caching is used) */
$this->directory_list->getPath('cache');

/* Get logs of system messages and errors */
$this->directory_list->getPath('log');

/* Get file system session directory (if file system session storage is used) */
$this->directory_list->getPath('session');

/* Get directory for Setup application*/
$this->directory_list->getPath('setup');

/* Get Dependency injection related file directory */
$this->directory_list->getPath('di');

/* Relative directory key for generated code*/
$this->directory_list->getPath('generation');

/* Temporary directory for uploading files by end-user */
$this->directory_list->getPath('upload');

/* Directory to store composer related files (config, cache etc.) in case if composer runs by Magento Application */
$this->directory_list->getPath('composer_home');

/* A suffix for temporary materialization directory where pre-processed files will be written (if necessary) */
$this->directory_list->getPath('view_preprocessed');

/* Get template minification dir */
$this->directory_list->getPath('html');
```

Comment: it returns browser url of media...i need the folder path of media

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: till not working.

Comment: Thank you @MohitKumarArora -- saved my day. the above solution worked like charm

Answer (score 7):

Try to get it by using **StoreManagerInterface**

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Now get media url using

```
 $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

Comment: not working.....

Answer (score 6):

Use below code to get the media path on .phtml file.

```
$this->getUrl('pub/media');
```

**By Objectmanager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

Comment: It returns the browser url path.. I need the folder path of media

Answer (score 0):

To get media path use below code

```
$this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath("folder_name")
```