# Magento 2 : How to get Custom module's 'web' directory path/Get custom module image directory path

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, directory

I have created a custom module in which I want to check if a (image)file exists in my `view/frontend/web/images` folder.

I have checked [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176492/23825) answer but in only shows how to get Magento's directory paths.

How can I get full path for my module's directory which will support with Magento 2's static content deploy feature?

**EDIT**

As per Rakesh's [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180413/23825) I can use below code.

```
$mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::APP)->getAbsolutePath();
$modulePath = echo $mediapath.'code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/images';
```

Is there any other alternative to this approach?

Comment: Alternativa way is look like pass path in function, $mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::APP)->getAbsolutePath('code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/images');

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, I am looking something like we use to get URL e.g. `$block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module/images/blank.png');`

Comment: Are you looking for path or url?

Comment: I am looking for path. I just provided example how Magento gets URL. So is there any code like that which can give us path just like getting URL.

Comment: Check answer with example, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-modules-view-directory-image-or-js-full-path-using-magento-2/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use code below to get module directory path

```
class CustomModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
     */
    protected $moduleReader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
    ) {
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    }

    public function getDirectory()
    {
        $viewDir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(
            \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
            'Vendor_Module'
        );
        return $viewDir . '/frontend/web/images';
    }
}
```

but if you need to check content static file I'd recommend you to use this way...

```
class CustomModel
{
/**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository
    ) {
        $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
    }

    public function getMyFilePath()
    {
        $fileId = 'Vendor_Module::images/myimage.png';
        $params = [
            'area' => 'frontend'
        ];
        $asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset($fileId, $params);
        try {
            return $asset->getSourceFile();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. This seems a better approach than using full directory path.

Comment: if you need to check content static file, I'd recommend another one way. Added to answer.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I was just implementing it with my code. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Magento\Framework\Module\Dir` Class to get Directory path of the module:

EXample:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $dir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\Dir');
    /*Retrieve full path to a directory of certain type within a module*/
    echo $dir->getDir('Magento_Customer');
    echo $dir->getDir('Magento_Customer','Controller');
```

Syntax:

```
    getDir('Module_Name','Directories');                                      
    /*getDir method not allow to read type of module's directory except these*/
    const MODULE_ETC_DIR = 'etc';
    const MODULE_I18N_DIR = 'i18n';
    const MODULE_VIEW_DIR = 'view';
    const MODULE_CONTROLLER_DIR = 'Controller';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get module's images path like this:
`$block->getViewFileUrl('VendorName_ModuleName::images/image.jpg)`.

Comment: Underrated answer. Easy and clean

Answer (score 1):

First just get your App folder path after getting app path you can got it by add your sub path,

```
  use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function getPathofmodule(){
        $mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::APP)->getAbsolutePath();
        $modulePath = echo $mediapath.'code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/images';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. This is what I thought too. But isn't there any other, better way to do it instead of using full directory path?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya How to access this image in web,after getting the absolute path  ?

Comment: @AdityaShah https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-modules-view-directory-image-or-js-full-path-using-magento-2/ answer in details.

Comment: Note that if you plan to package your module in order to use it with composer, this solution won't work, because the module will be located in the vendor folder.