# Magento 2 : How To Get Modules Directory Path In Controller

Tags: magento2, module

Does Anyone Know how can we get module file system path in magento 2 inside controller ?

Comment: I explained few thing about the get module direct path in the module here is the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261062/65820.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use code below to get module directory path**

```
class CustomModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
     */
    protected $moduleReader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
    ) {
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    }

    public function getDirectory()
    {
        $viewDir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(
            \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
            'Vendor_Module'
        );
        return $viewDir . '/frontend/web/images'; //your file path
    }
}
```