# Read input csv file and convert it to array

Tags: magento2, import, csv, importexport, file-upload

I have an input file form in phtml to import data from csv file type like this:

```
<div class="import-shipping">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>CSV File:</h4>
  </div>
  <form class="import-shipping-form" action="<?= $postUrl ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <input type="file" required class="required-entry" name="csv" />
    <button type="submit">Import</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

How can i read   the csv file and turn it into an array, and validate the file input file type is csv in my controller?

for example my csv file look like this:

[image: csv file example]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your controller file that `$postUrl` points to:

```
protected $csv;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv
)
{
     $this->csv = $csv;
}

//The function name should match your controller path
public function import($file)
{
     if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) 
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));
     
     $csvData = $this->csv->getData($file['tmp_name']);

     foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
         if ($row > 0){
             //Start your work
         }
     }
     die();
}
```

Note:

1. The `$data` is an array object already. It will look like `array( 0 => 'UPS', 1 => 'One Night Service' ...... )`
2. I added `if ($row > 0)` to skip the first row as it's the attribute row only.
3. You must `die()` the execution after your job is done.
   I assume your controller is custom-made. If you want to override the core controller,  please see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2).

Ref: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-readwrite-csv-file-from-magento/

Comment: How can I read data from csv that I have uploaded in pub/media folder. I have added the path as $file. But its not detecting file. Its says file doesn't exists.

Comment: You can refer to this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176490/how-to-get-media-directory-path-in-a-phtml-file-in-magento-2

Comment: It shows me JavaScript may be disabled in your browser. To use this website you must first enable JavaScript in your browser. But my javascript is enabled error and reload the page will you please help me with this @PYYick

Answer (score 5):

This it the controller file to save/read imported CSV data:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Pincode\Import;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Vendor_ModuleName::manage_pincodes';

    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Ktpl\BannerSlider\BannerImageUploader
     */
    private $csvUploader;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
     */
    protected $_filesystem;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * CSV Processor
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Csv
     */
    protected $csvProcessor;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        try {
            if(isset($data['file_upload']['0'])) {
                $data['file_upload'] = $data['file_upload']['0']['name'];
            }
            else {
                $data['file_upload'] = null;
            }

            if(isset($data['file_upload']) && !is_null($data['file_upload']))
            {
                $this->getCSVUploader()->moveFileFromTmp($data['file_upload']);

                $mediaPath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath()
                     . '<moduleroute_code>/pincode/' . $data['file_upload'];

                $importProductRawData = $this->csvProcessor->getData($mediaPath);

                $count = 0;

                foreach ($importProductRawData as $rowIndex => $dataRow) 
                {
                    if($rowIndex > 0) 
                    {
                        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('<Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Model\Pincode');

                        $model->loadByPincode($dataRow[0])
                            ->setData('pincode', $dataRow[0])
                            ->setData('is_cod_available', $dataRow[1])
                            ->setData('delivery_time', $dataRow[2])
                            ->setData('delivery_message', $dataRow[3])
                            ->setData('is_active', $dataRow[4])
                            ->save();

                        $count++;
                    }
                }

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Total %1 pincodes added / updated successfully.', $count));
            }
            else
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('CSV file not uploaded properly, please try again!'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/pincode/index');
    }

    /**
     * Get image uploader
     *
     * @return \Ktpl\BannerSlider\BannerImageUploader
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getCSVUploader()
    {
        if ($this->csvUploader === null) {
            $this->csvUploader = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                '<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\CsvUploader'
            );
        }
        return $this->csvUploader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of above code snippet can be used to only `read` data from csv file?

Answer (score 0):

*If your .csv file is import by manually then read .csv file data in Array Object*

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv)
        {
          $this->csv = $csv;
        }
        /**
         * Execute observer
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
          $csvData = $this->csv->getData($_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name']);
          foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
            if ($row > 0){
              echo "<pre>";
              print_r($data);
                }
              }
        die();
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

If your .csv file is in pub media folder or other folder.

You can read csv file simply by: 
you just have to give your .csv path like pub/media, root of magento etc in $file.

```
$file = 'csv/products.csv';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if (empty($handle) === false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        var_dump($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
```