# Add JS on condition

Tags: magento2, javascript, event-observer

I'm want to add a dynamic js remote file in my website. So far, I've added CSS file thanks to this, but I can't achieve to add CSS files.

I've an observer with that.

```
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="addCSS" instance="Portail\Axiane\Observer\AddCSS" shared="false" />
 </event>
```

My observer

```
   public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $page */
        $page = $om->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');

        /** @var Http $request */
        $request = $observer->getRequest();
            $route_name = $request->getRouteName();
            if ($route_name == "test") {
                $remote = "http://...";
                $script_src = "$remote/static/freb.js";
                $properties = [
                    'attributes' =>
                        [
                            "att1" => "1",
                            "att2" => "2",
                        ]
                ];
                $page->addRemotePageAsset($script_src, "text/javascript", $properties);
            
        }
}
```

But the JS is added as a CSS, without the **script/src** but with a **link/href**  in the **head**

Answer (score 0):

> **Follow Below Steps**

> **Step-1 :** Create routes.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc/frontend and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customlayout" id="customlayout">
            <module name="VendoreName_CustomLayout"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Step-2 :** Create Index.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Controller/Index and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> **Step-3 :** Create customlayout_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::css/my_custom_layout_css.css" />
        <script src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::js/my_custom_layout_js.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Here the file name must be like **routename_controllername_actionname.xml** and all characters must be in lowercase.

*Add your css to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/css/my_custom_layout_css.css*

*Add your Js to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/js/my_custom_layout_js.js*

> **Step-4 :** Create events.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_layout_css_js_add" instance="VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer\CustomLayoutHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

***You can also use your event***

**we need to add to css and js before page layout that's why we use layout_load_before event.**

> **Step-5 :** Create CustomLayoutHandler.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Observer and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer;

class CustomLayoutHandler implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $pageResult,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageResult = $pageResult;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // echo "string";exit();
        $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
        echo $blockFile = $layout->createBlock(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class)
            ->setTemplate("VendoreName_CustomLayout::customjs.phtml")->toHtml();
        // $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        // $currentPageLayout = $this->_pageResult->getConfig()->getPageLayout();
        // if ($currentPageLayout == "customlayout") {
        //     $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customlayout_index_index');
        // }

    }
}
```

Add below code to your customjs.phtml file

```
<script src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendorename_ModuleName::js/script.js').'?param=12';  ?>"></script>
```

> **Step-6 :** Run mgento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: How can I add dynamic attributes to my script JS (step 3) ?

Comment: you can set attribute as into array and use with like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11149036

Comment: create array of your attribute and access it into you js by using window.variableName

Comment: I don't get it. What I need is to have something like this at the end :   <script 
   src="https://..."
   kr-public-key="..."
   kr-post-url-success="...">
  </script>

Comment: you can add js file to using phtml also please check it updated answer and update me.

Comment: I can't dowload the remote file. And if I had "?param=", wil this work as if i add attributes to my <script> ?

Comment: you need t place your js file at above path which is in the post and yes you can use your attribute to your <script>

Comment: app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/js/yourfilename.js

Comment: When I meen "I can't dowload the file", it meens "I can't download the file". This is an API remote file and I can't keep it on my local server (because of update etc...)

Comment: you can create file path using this please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176493/82670  after file path ready then assige to src.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module with name **M2Expert_Js** by following below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/M2Expert/Js/registration.php

with content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'M2Expert_Js',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/M2Expert/Js/etc/module.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="M2Expert_Js" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **events.xml** under:

> app/code/M2Expert/Js/etc/frontend/events.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="m2expert_js_layout_render" instance="M2Expert\Js\Observer\LayoutRender" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 5:**
Create **LayoutRender.php** under:

> app/code/M2Expert/Js/Observer/LayoutRender.php

with content:

```
<?php
namespace M2Expert\Js\Observer;

class LayoutRender implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getData('full_action_name');
        if($action == 'your_action_name')
            $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('m2expert_dynamic_js');
        }

        return $observer;
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**
Create **LayoutRender.php** under:

> app/code/M2Expert/Js/view/frontend/layout/m2expert_dynamic_js.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="http://example.com/abc.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Flush the cache and run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile and static:content:deploy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up by adding this into my layout xml (which is kind of a mix of suggested answer)

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Scripts" name="frontuser_scripts" template="Magento_Theme::html/scripts.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

And simply getting params like this in my **scripts.phtml**

```
<?php

$client = $this->get_pz_client();
?>
<script
    src="<?php echo $client->getClientEndpoint();?>..scripts.min.js"
    public-key="<?php echo $client->getPublicKey();?>"
    post-url-success="paid.php">
</script>
```