# Include js file script in php observer file

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, event-observer, magento2.3.5

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p2

I am adding a new module to add an Observer that will trigger some js code during an event that happens

below are the file and its content I have added

File Name and Path :
`app/code/Vendor/MyModule/registration.php`

Content :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_MyModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

File Name and Path :
`app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/module.xml`

Content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

File Name and Path :

```
app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/events.xml
```

Content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="wishlist_add_product">
        <observer name="myObserverNameWishlistAddProduct" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\WishlistAddProduct" />
    </event>
    <event name="wishlist_add_item">
        <observer name="myObserverNameWishlistAddItem" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\WishlistAddItem" />
    </event>
    <event name="wishlist_update_item">
        <observer name="myObserverNameWishlistUpdateItem" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\WishlistUpdateItem" />
    </event>
    <event name="wishlist_product_add_after">
        <observer name="myObserverNameWishlistProductAddAfter" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\WishlistProductAddAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File Name and Path for Observer to trigger during wishlist add an item :

`app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Observer/WishlistAddItem.php`

Content :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class WishlistAddItem implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    // Observer initialization code...
    // You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
  }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    // Observer execution code...
    $myEventData = $observer->getData('myEventData');

    var_dump('wishlist_add_item');die;
  }
}


?>
```

File Name and Path for Observer to trigger during wishlist product add after

`app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Observer/WishlistProductAddAfter.php`

Content :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class WishlistProductAddAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    // Observer initialization code...
    // You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
  }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    // Observer execution code...
    $myEventData = $observer->getData('myEventData');

    var_dump('wishlist_product_add_after');die;
  }
}


?>
```

the code above is able to work perfectly fine, and I am able to get the below output when adding an item to the wishlist

```
string(26) "wishlist_product_add_after"
```

but now I want to add a javascript code when an observer is executed

so instead of `var_dump('wishlist_product_add_after')`

it will be something like

```
<script>

dataLayer.push({
'event': 'trackEvent',
'eventDetails.category': 'product search result engagement',
'eventDetails.action': 'add to wish list',
'eventDetails.label': '18 grains dried fruits granola (7 X 40g) X 4 packs',

//product name
'sellingPrice': '103.00', //selling price
'salePrice': '115.20', //sale price
'productID': '1329543075804', //product id
'productName': '18 grains dried fruits granola (7 X 40g) X 4 packs',

//product name
'productCategory': 'grocery', //product category
'marketPrice': '200.00', //market price
'shippingWestMalaysia': '0.00', //shipping fee
'shippingEastMalaysia': '4.00' //shipping fee

});

</script>
```

how do I add this type of javascript code inside the PHP observable file?

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327087/add-js-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

You can bind his into event observer by echo statement like this one :

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'dataLayer.push({';
.......
.......
.......
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to achieve what you want by using php observers. In this particular case, when you press an *'Add to Wishlist'* button, a post request is sent. During this request, the mentioned observer events are triggered. And when the request is finished, it returns a 302 redirect to the Wishlist overview page. So if you add some content in your observer, it will not work.

I guess you'd better add a [mixin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) for the *vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/web/js/add-to-wishlist.js* widget. Here is how you can do it:

**1. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Wishlist/js/add-to-wishlist': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/add-to-wishlist-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**2. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/add-to-wishlist-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (addToWishlistWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.addToWishlist', addToWishlistWidget, {
            _bind: function () {
                this._super();

                var updateWishlist = 'click ' + this.options.actionElement,
                    additionalEvents = {};

                additionalEvents[updateWishlist] = 'updateDataLayer';

                this._on(additionalEvents);
            },

            updateDataLayer: function () {
                if (dataLayer) {
                    dataLayer.push({
                        // ...
                        // event info here
                        // ...
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        return $.mage.addToWishlist;
    };
});
```

Comment: can you help explain on how this code works, I try putting console.log at certain line, apparently the code inside _bind: function() { are triggered when user refresh on the page, I tried console.log inside updateDataLayer but seems like it is not read when I try adding item to wishlist