# Right way to link image resources

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module serving a template with the following img tag:

```
<img src="http://example.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Company_Module/images/berry.jpg" alt="berrylicious">
```

Certainly, there has to be a better way to include static files.

Should I be declaring these images in a layout file? Is there a shortcut I can use to link to the static files?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155238/33057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php $block->getViewFileUrl('Company_Module/images/berry.jpg') ?>" />
```

It should help.