# Magento 2 Best way to link images in a template file

Tags: magento2.2, template

I am building a module which needs to link an image. I have followed several resources on this, but none worked ([example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155235/add-images-in-magento-theme-template-file/155238#155238)).

Module is working fine, but I can't show the image. What goes wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your image in module frontend:

1. Add your image in : `app/code/Vendor/Name/view/frontend/web/images/yourimage.png`
2. Load your image in your phtml module in : `app/code/Vendor/Name/view/frontend/templates/yourfile.phtml` and like this :

   ```
   <img class="someClass" alt="imageName" src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Name::images/yourimage.png'); ?>">
   ```

**NB:**  dont forget to deploy the static-content like this :

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: The thing is, I already tried this approach before but and it didn't work. But I probably messed up something, because now it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, maybe you were wrong in the folders path or uppercases or ..., that helped you and it's cool, good luck

Answer (score 1):

Put your image in below folder :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/images

then use :

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/xyz.jpg'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: I tried the above and it did work. Your solution probably is better for module independent templates. Thank you for your time!